# Sorting all worksheets in the workbook

Tags: vba, excel, sorting, copy

I have this code that actually do exactly what I want to:

goes to the specific range, copy the table in a new range and reorder the table.

Here is the code:

```
 Sub copy_paste_sort()

Dim oneRange As Range
Dim aCell As Range
Dim WS_Count As Integer
Dim I As Integer

         ' Set WS_Count equal to the number of worksheets in the active
         ' workbook.
WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

         ' Begin the loop.
    For I = 1 To WS_Count

Set oneRange = Range("CZ269:DA294")
Set aCell = Range("DA269")

Range("CW269:CX294").Select
Selection.Copy

Range("CZ269:DA294").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

oneRange.Sort Key1:=aCell, Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo


    Next I

End Sub
```

The problem is: the code is not working in all worksheets, it is repeating n times in the first worksheet.

Comment: You need to qualify your references to `Range`, etc, to refer to which worksheet you want to use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You never tell the code to go to the next worksheet. Also, your selections don't look necessary.

```
 Sub copy_paste_sort()

Dim oneRange As Range
Dim aCell As Range
Dim WS_Count As Integer
Dim I As Integer

         ' Set WS_Count equal to the number of worksheets in the active
         ' workbook.
WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

         ' Begin the loop.
    For I = 1 To WS_Count

Set oneRange = worksheets(I).Range("CZ269:DA294")
Set aCell = worksheets(I).Range("DA269")

worksheets(I).Range("CW269:CX294").Copy  worksheets(I).Range("CZ269:DA294")

oneRange.Sort Key1:=aCell, Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo


    Next I

End Sub
```

Also  - Since you are sorting the range, I am guessing that it containsvalues, rather than formulas.  If that is the case, you can replace

`worksheets(I).Range("CW269:CX294").Copy  worksheets(I).Range("CZ269:DA294")`

with

`worksheets(I).Range("CZ269:DA294").Value = worksheets(I).Range("CW269:CX294").Value`

The advantage of this is that it is slightly faster, and doesn't use your clipboard.

Comment: didn't work. the code stops in worksheets(I).Range("CW269:CX294").Copy, error 438 "object doesn't support this property or method

Answer (score 2):

Try it as,

```
Sub copy_paste_sort()

    Dim I As Long

    ' Begin the loop.
    For I = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
        With Worksheets(I)

            With .Range("CW269:CX294")
                .Copy destination:=.Range("CZ269")
                .Offset(0, 3).Cells.Sort Key1:=aCell, Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo
            End With
        End With
    Next I


End Sub
```

You were looping through `I` as the index number of the workshjeets but not doing anything with it. The `With Worksheets(I) ... End With` references eac h worksheet in turn. Note that `Range(...)` becomes `.Range(...)` so that it knows what worksheet is its parent.